# 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value'

Tags: anchor

I have updated Anchor to `^0.29.0`, Solana to `1.16.18` (did try `1.17.4`), and Rust Compiler to `1.73.0`. The `anchor build` runs successfully, however, the `anchor test` always throws this exception. I have tried every possible set of versions in the last 2 days without any positive results.

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', cli/src/lib.rs:3128:55
> note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

Does anyone know how to fix it? thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I recognize a weird behaviour. After reset the laptop, if I run the `yarn` first, I will got the error mentioned above. However, if I run the `anchor test` first, it will pass the test but I will get the error of `zsh: segmentation fault  yarn` when run any yarn commands.

Comment: I'm using `yarn` 1.22

Comment: I also tried with yarn 4.0 but the error still persists.

Comment: You should probably submit an issue to Anchor directly at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues, this seems like a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a conflict between `yarn` and `anchor`. Remove all the `yarn`-related files and use `pnpm` instead, it will work perfectly.

I may keep this problem open because this solution is a workaround and not solve the root.